# Xcode 8 Swift 3 distribution crash on launch

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am running my project on **Xcode 8** and **Swift 3**.

I deploy the build to client by **TestFlight**, but each time on launch the app crash without crashlog on **Xcode** Organizer(only get **.ips.beta** format file). The build works well on **iOS 10** under **iPhone 6s**.

**device** **iPhone5s** **iOS 9.3**
My **Xcode** deployment version 9.0 or 9.3 (both doesn't work)

Anyone has any suggestions? thanks!

Comment: For anyone has the familiar issue please check if any `nil` or some properties of Singleton method/properties return nil. I spend a long time to figure this out.